# sProcessItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ Not Functioning As Expected

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

PROBLEM:

When running my program after entering the 3 text fields, you are supposed to click Process Item #1  before then click confirm - however this does not occur as expected - when you click process Item it does nothing.

REQUIREMENT:

When clicking Process Item #1 I need it to process the order - I tried to achieve this by calling:

```
sProcessItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sStoreAction.ProcessOrder(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()), Integer.valueOf(sNumItemsTF.getText()));
                if(sCurrentOrderNumber < Integer.valueOf(sNumItemsTF.getText())){
                    sNumItemsTF.setEditable(false);
                    sNumItemsTF.setEditable(false);
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(true);
                    sProcessItem.setEnabled(false);

                    sIDTF.setText("");
                    sQuantityTF.setText("");
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
                    //sCurrentOrderNumber++;
                    RedrawLabels();
                }else{
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
                    sProcessItem.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

FULL SOURCE:

```
package theCDstore;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;



public class Store_GUI {

    private  CDobject sCD;
    private  int sCurrentOrderNumber;
    private  JFrame sStoreWindow;
    private  JPanel sPanel;
    private  SpringLayout sLayout;
    private  Store_backend sStoreAction;

    private  JTextField sNumItemsTF;
    private  JTextField sIDTF;
    private  JTextField sQuantityTF;
    private  JTextField sItemInfoTF;
    private  JTextField sSubtotalTF;

    private  JLabel sNumItemsL;
    private  JLabel sIDL;
    private  JLabel sQuantityL;
    private  JLabel sItemInfoL;
    private  JLabel sSubtotalL;

    private  JButton sProcessItem;
    private  JButton sConfirmItem;
    private  JButton sViewOrder;
    private  JButton sFinishOrder;
    private  JButton sNewOrder;
    private  JButton sExit;

    /**
     * Starts the initialization of the JFrame, and initializes the StoreAction object.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Store_GUI().StartThread();
        sCurrentOrderNumber = 1;
        InitWindow();

    }

    /**
     * Sets many of the base attributes of the frame/panel and calls other methods to populate it.
     */
    private  void InitWindow(){
        sStoreWindow = new JFrame("Adrian's Wonderful World of Music");
        sPanel  = new JPanel();

        sPanel.setSize(1000, 300);
        sStoreWindow.setSize(1000, 300);

        InitButtons();

        InitLabels();

        InitText();

        InitPlacement();

        sStoreWindow.add(sPanel);
        sStoreWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the JLabels and adds them to the panel.
     */
    private  void InitLabels(){
        sNumItemsL = new JLabel("Enter the number of items for this order:");
        sIDL = new JLabel("Enter CD ID for item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+":");
        sQuantityL = new JLabel("Enter quantity for item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+":");
        sItemInfoL = new JLabel("Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+" info:");
        sSubtotalL = new JLabel("Order subtotal for "+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber-1)+" item(s):");

        sPanel.add(sNumItemsL);
        sPanel.add(sIDL);
        sPanel.add(sQuantityL);
        sPanel.add(sItemInfoL);
        sPanel.add(sSubtotalL);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the JTextFields and adds listeners to them.
     */
    private  void InitText(){
        sNumItemsTF = new JTextField(13);
        sIDTF = new JTextField(13);
        sQuantityTF = new JTextField(13);
        sItemInfoTF = new JTextField(40);
        sSubtotalTF = new JTextField(13);

        sIDTF.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                if((arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) && !sIDTF.getText().isEmpty()){
                    sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()));
                    if(!sQuantityTF.getText().isEmpty())
                        sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));
                    else
                        sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, 1);
                    AutoComplete(sCD);
                }

            }});
        sIDTF.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                if(!sIDTF.getText().isEmpty()){
                    sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()));

                    if(!sQuantityTF.getText().isEmpty())
                        sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));
                    else
                        sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, 1);

                    AutoComplete(sCD);
                }
            }

        });
        sQuantityTF.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if(!sQuantityTF.getText().isEmpty() && !sIDTF.getText().isEmpty()){
//                  sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()),Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));
                    sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()));

                    sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));

                    AutoComplete(sCD);
                }

            }});
        sQuantityTF.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                if(Character.isDigit(arg0.getKeyChar())){
//                  sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()),Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));
                    sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()));
                    sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));

                    AutoComplete(sCD);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            }});

        sItemInfoTF.setEnabled(false);
        sSubtotalTF.setEditable(false);

        sPanel.add(sNumItemsTF);
        sPanel.add(sIDTF);
        sPanel.add(sQuantityTF);
        sPanel.add(sItemInfoTF);
        sPanel.add(sSubtotalTF);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the JButtons and adds listeners to them.
     */
    private  void InitButtons(){
        sProcessItem = new JButton("Process Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+"");
        sConfirmItem = new JButton("Confirm Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+"");
        sViewOrder = new JButton("View Order");
        sFinishOrder = new JButton("Finish Order");
        sNewOrder = new JButton("New Order");
        sExit = new JButton("Exit");

        sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
        sViewOrder.setEnabled(false);
        sFinishOrder.setEnabled(false);

        sProcessItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sStoreAction.ProcessOrder(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()), Integer.valueOf(sNumItemsTF.getText()));
                if(sCurrentOrderNumber < Integer.valueOf(sNumItemsTF.getText())){
                    sNumItemsTF.setEditable(false);
                    sNumItemsTF.setEditable(false);
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(true);
                    sProcessItem.setEnabled(false);

                    sIDTF.setText("");
                    sQuantityTF.setText("");
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
                    //sCurrentOrderNumber++;
                    RedrawLabels();
                }else{
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
                    sProcessItem.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }});
        sConfirmItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sPanel,"Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+" accepted");
                sNumItemsTF.setEditable(false);
                sProcessItem.setEnabled(true);
                sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
            }});
        sViewOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sPanel, sStoreAction.getDisplayViewOrder());
            }});
        sFinishOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sPanel, sStoreAction.DisplayInvoice());
                sStoreAction.WriteInvoice();
                NewOrderClick();
            }});
        sNewOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                NewOrderClick();
            }});
        sExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sStoreWindow.dispose();
            }});

        sPanel.add(sProcessItem);
        sPanel.add(sConfirmItem);
        sPanel.add(sViewOrder);
        sPanel.add(sFinishOrder);
        sPanel.add(sNewOrder);
        sPanel.add(sExit);
    }

    /**
     * Positions all of the objects in the JPanel using SpringLayout.
     */
    private  void InitPlacement(){
        sLayout = new SpringLayout();
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sNumItemsL, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH,sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sNumItemsTF, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH,sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sNumItemsL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sNumItemsTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sNumItemsL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sIDL, 7, SpringLayout.SOUTH,sNumItemsL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sIDL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sIDTF, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sNumItemsTF);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sIDTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sIDL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sQuantityL, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH,sIDL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sQuantityL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sQuantityTF, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sIDTF);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sQuantityTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sQuantityL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sItemInfoL, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH,sQuantityL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sItemInfoL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sItemInfoTF, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sQuantityTF);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sItemInfoTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sItemInfoL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sSubtotalL, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH,sItemInfoL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sSubtotalL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sSubtotalTF, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sItemInfoTF);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sSubtotalTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sSubtotalL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sProcessItem, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sConfirmItem, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sViewOrder, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sFinishOrder, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sNewOrder, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sExit, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sProcessItem, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sConfirmItem, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sProcessItem);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sViewOrder, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sConfirmItem);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sFinishOrder, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sViewOrder);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sNewOrder, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sFinishOrder);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sExit, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sNewOrder);

        sPanel.setLayout(sLayout);
    }

    /**
     * Auto fills the Info, Subtotal, and if necessary the Quantity text boxes.
     * @param mCD The current CD object.
     */
    private  void AutoComplete(CDobject mCD){
        sItemInfoTF.setText(mCD.getInfo());
        if(!sQuantityTF.getText().isEmpty())
            sSubtotalTF.setText(String.valueOf(sStoreAction.getDisplaySubtotal(mCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()))));
        else{
            sQuantityTF.setText("1");
            sSubtotalTF.setText(String.valueOf(sStoreAction.getDisplaySubtotal(mCD,1)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the items number of many of the labels based on the sCurrentOrderNumber.
     */
    private  void RedrawLabels(){
        sProcessItem.setText("Process Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+"");
        sConfirmItem.setText("Confirm Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+"");
        sIDL.setText("Enter CD ID for item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+":");
        sQuantityL.setText("Enter quantity for item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+":");
        sItemInfoL.setText("Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+" info:");
        sSubtotalL.setText("Order subtotal for "+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber-1)+" item(s):");
    }

    /**
     * Clears the text fields, reinitializes the StoreAction object, and redraws the labels.
     */
    private  void NewOrderClick(){
        new Store_GUI().StartThread();
        sCurrentOrderNumber = 1;

        sIDTF.setText("");
        sQuantityTF.setText("");
        sItemInfoTF.setText("");
        sSubtotalTF.setText("");
        sNumItemsTF.setText("");

        RedrawLabels();

        sNumItemsTF.setEditable(true);
        sConfirmItem.setEnabled(true);
        sProcessItem.setEnabled(false);
    }


    /**
     * Defines a new class to execute the initialization of Store Action on its own thread.
     * @author david
     */
    class NewThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sStoreAction = new Store_backend();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts the thread.
     */
    private void StartThread(){
        new NewThread().start();
    }

}


RESULTS (after removing static):

Error: 

    Main method is not static in class theCDstore.Store_GUI, please define the main method as:
       public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in an IDE debugger and stepping through the code?  Nobody is going to read all that to find your problem.  Please read the [FAQ] an [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.

Comment: Yes - when I set a breakpoint at NewOrderClick();
    }else{ it runs over it but never starts my NewOrderClick method


Thanks for the pro tip - but I've already read it.

Comment: "Pro" tip #2: get rid of all those statics.

Comment: Which static? Every one except the main method.

Comment: I did exactly that and I'm getting: Error: Main method is not static in class theCDstore.Store_GUI, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args) 


(I can show you if you'd like)

Comment: Again, the main method **should** be static. Everything else shouldn't.

Comment: I'll edit - I tried and got an error

Comment: I added the method I used to implement your suggestion in my most recent edit

Comment: ***Again*** the main method **should** be static. Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: It is: public static void main(String[] args) (did you see my edit - when I tried changing everything after the main method to non static its throwing an error)

Comment: What I see in your code is: `public  void main(String[] args) {`. No static. Please double check your code.

Comment: Your problem is that in your main method, you're trying to access the instance fields and methods of your class in a static way which is wrong. Don't do that. Create and initialize a Store_GUI **variable** in the main method, call `startThread()` on this intance, then `initWindow()` *on the instance*. Don't call it without the instance because then you're trying to access the method in a static way. And never directly manipulate the fields of your class from another class. To be blunt, it's very bad form to do what you're doing, and will give you a program that can't be extended.

Comment: FYI - When I change my main method to static and leave all the others non-static I'm getting an error stating: 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sCurrentOrderNumber & Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method InitWindow() from the type Store_GUI Store_GUI.java

Comment: Then when I proceed to change InitWindow to static  and or sCurrentOrderNumber to static (as eclipse suggests) I end up with 11 new errors...

Comment: ERRORS: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sStoreWindow
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sPanel Store_GUI.java 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sStoreWindow 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sPanel 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sStoreWindow 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method InitButtons()

Answer (score 0):

Per your comments:

> FYI - When I change my main method to static and leave all the others non-static I'm getting an error stating: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sCurrentOrderNumber & Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method InitWindow() from the type Store_GUI  Store_GUI.java**strong text**

Which I've already addressed in my comment above yours:

Your problem is that in your main method, you're trying to access the instance fields and methods of your class in a static way which is wrong. Don't do that. Create and initialize a Store_GUI ***variable*** in the main method, call `startThread()` on this instance, then `initWindow()` on the instance. Don't call it without the instance because then you're trying to access the method in a static way. And never directly manipulate the fields of your class from another class.

Again, by making everything static, you are fixing the wrong thing. The solution is not to make variables and methods static, but to avoid trying to access them in a static way.

i.e.,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Store_GUI store = new Store_GUI();
  store.StartThread();
  store.InitWindow();

  // !! new Store_GUI().StartThread();
  // sCurrentOrderNumber = 1;
  // InitWindow();
}
```

This has nothing to do with Swing or GUI's and all to do with basic programming techniques.